# How to use Facebook-Like Button in IPhone Standalone WebApp

Tags: iphone-standalone-web-app

In an iPhone Standalone WebApp I want to include a normal facebook like and share button.

The problem:
Iphone opens the Facebook Popup-Window fullscreen in the App Browser where the user has no back button, so the user is trapped there.

Is there a way to force the Facebook-Button to open the Popup as a page in Safari, like normal a href links?